# ng-include using scope variables not working

Tags: angularjs

So I am trying to add an ng-include for my side bar content but it is not working.

app.js

```
...
gvhsApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.template = 'views/mainSidebar.html';
});
```

index.html

```
...
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div ng-include src="template"> </div>
</div>
```

I am not seeing any errors in my chrome console. Could it be I am not pointing to the file location properly?

Edit:

Directory Structure

```
app/
   js/
      app.js
   views/
      index.html
      templates/
          mainSidebar.html
build/
   js/
      app.js
   views/
      index.html
      mainSidebar.html
```

The build directory is where my server is looking at

Comment: You might need to do: `<div ng-include src="{{template}}"> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-include` doesn't automatically resolve the `src` value to an expression - it just expects text. Use mustaches inside the value:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div ng-include src="{{template}}"> </div>
</div>
```

This of course assumes that the `<div>` is inside an Angular-enabled view and bound to the controller correctly.

Comment: The problem was I was not putting that code inside the ng-view. Once I did that it worked